# axios.put is not working when sending query object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I was trying to send put request using axios to update information about a book in mongodb, the code is working fine when using postman but it is not working using axios.put used inside react component when submitting, while axios.delete is working fine. I think the problem is that sending the query object in that way is not the right way but I am not able to find the solution.
This is the function that handleSubmit,

- the 'id' is the id of the book
- 'updates' is a state object that contains all the changes that should happen in the book data.
- And the second function handleChange is the function that setupdates according to changes in the inputs

  ```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios.put("http://localhost:8000/book/edit/" + id, {
        params: {
          updates,
        },
      });
    setNewBook(res.data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

     const handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const value = e.target.value;
        setUpdates({
          ...updates,
          [e.target.name]: value,
        });
      };
  ```

Comment: Hello Rabih! Seems too broad of a question. Do you get any error or logs , is the URL right (http/https) , have you used a proxy (TCPMon) and see what is the payload sent and to what URL

Comment: This issue comes up so often! Does nobody read [the Axios docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro#request-method-aliases)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you misunderstood the axios put method. as per the axios docs provided (https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosputurl-data-config) the correct structure is `axios.put(url[, data[, config]])`

- The first parameter is URL
- The second parameter is data (body request).
- 3rd parameter is config (you leave params in this parameter)

It should be like this

```
const res = await axios.put("http://localhost:8000/book/edit/" + id, null, {
       params: {
         updates,
       },
     });
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: thanks, it works when adding (null) and (...updates) instead of updates